# Ist »promptlich« das Adverb zu »prompt«?

Tags: adjective, adverb

Es gibt das Adjektiv *prompt* im Deutschen.
Darf ich daraus ein Adverb machen, z.B ***promptlich***?

Es gibt auch das Wort *pünktlich*, das die gleiche Bedeutung hat, z. B.:

> Wir haben Ihre Bestellung pünktlich rausgeschickt.

Auf Englisch würde ich sagen:

> We shipped your order promptly.

Kann man auch »promptlich rausgeschickt« sagen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Nein.

Adjektive und Adverbien unterscheiden sich im Deutschen rein äußerlich nicht. Etwas wie die englische Endsilbe »-ly«, die man an ein Adjektiv anhängen kann um es zu einem Adverb zu machen, gibt es nicht.

**Adverbien:**

> Wir haben Ihre Bestellung **pünktlich** rausgeschickt.
>   Wir haben Ihre Bestellung **prompt** rausgeschickt.

**Adjektive:**

> Der Kunde lobte die **pünktliche** Lieferung.
>   Der Kunde lobte die **prompte** Lieferung.

Die Silbe »-lich« in »pünktlich« ist eine Folge der Abstammung von einem Substantiv (»der Punkt«). »Pünktlich« bedeutet wort-wörtlich »wie ein Punkt«, im Sinn von »auf den Punkt«.

Grammatisch unterscheiden sich die beiden Wortarten dadurch, dass ein Adjektiv gemeinsam mit dem Substantiv, zu dem es gehört, gebeugt wird:

> Das schnell**e** Auto ist rot. (Nominativ)
>   Die Farbe des schnell**en** Auto**s** gefällt mit. (Genitiv)
>   Ich sitze in dem schnell**en** Auto. (Dativ)
>   Jürgen hat ein schnell**es** Auto. (Akkusativ)

Adverbien beziehen sich nicht auf ein Substantiv, sondern auf ein Verb (manchmal auch auf ein Adjektiv), und werden nicht gebeugt.

Comment: Adjektive in prädikativer Stellung werden allerdings auch nicht flektiert, so wie das _rot_ in _Das schnelle Auto ist rot_.

Comment: Die Antwort enthält einen kleinen Fehler: es gibt mit *-weise* noch eine produktive Endung, die *nur* Adjektive erzeugt: "Ich bin rasenderweise nach Hamburg gefahren" vs falsch: "Der rasenderweise Fahrer". Die Endsilbe *-weise* betont, dass ein Ereignis auf *bestimmte Weise* geschehen ist.

Comment: @Veredomon: Du wolltest „die nur Adverbien erzeugt“ schreiben. ;-) Aber auch mit _-weise_ gebildete Wörter können Adjektive sein: _ein zeitweises Aussetzen des Programms_.

Comment: @Veredomon: Wenn das Verb substantiviert wird, wird das Adverb, das sich darauf bezog, zum Adjektiv, und das sogar auch dann, wenn da *-weise* dran hängt: »*Das rasenderweise Fahren nach Hamburg ist gefährlich.*«. Diese Konstruktion ist vergleichbar mit: Das *schluckweise* Trinken und das *stückweise* Zusammensetzen. Im *literweisen* Konsum (z.B. von Bier) muss ich nicht mal ein Verb substantivieren. Natürlich klingt »*das rasende Fahren*« besser als »*das rasenderweise Fahren*«, aber das trifft auch auf »Ich bin rasend gefahren« und »Ich bin rasenderweise gefahren« zu.

Comment: @chirlu: Bei Adjektiven in prädikativer Stellung kann man (muss aber nicht!) argumentieren, dass es sich dabei gar nicht um Adjektive, sondern eben um Adverbien handelt, denn sie modifizieren nicht das Subjekt, sondern das Verb, das eine Form von »sein« ist. In »Das Auto fährt schnell« und »Das Auto ist schnell« beschreibt »schnell« nicht das Auto (das Substantiv) selbst, sondern das Verb. »Schnell« beschreibt also auf welche Weise das Auto den Vorgang »fahren« vollführt, und auf welche Weise es den Vorgang »sein« vollführt. Natürlich ist diese Sichtweise ein wenig akademisch, aber denkbar.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Das ist richtig. Die Verwendung als Adjektiv ist jedoch, das fällt auf, stark an ein Verb gebunden. Ich halte die von uns benannten Einschränkungen jedoch für stark genug, um -weise vor allem als *echte* Adverbendung anzusehen. Anyway, ist nicht so wichtig in dem Kontext; ich werde es mir wohl mal genauer anschauen.

Comment: Ich finde *prompterweise* sollte in dieser sonst ausführlichen Antwort direkt erwähnt werden, auch wenn (oder sogar gerade weil) die Option eine Färbung hat die zum Beispiel nicht so gut passt.

Answer (score 5):

*Promptlich* ist gar kein Wort bzw. es ist eine spontane Ableitung von *prompt*, die so etwas ausdrückt wie *ein bisschen prompt* oder *promptartig*. Mit anderen Worten: Nicht prompt, aber eine Tendenz dazu ist erkennbar. Wenn jemand sagen würde „Ich habe es promptlich verschickt“, dann würde ich das ungefähr so verstehen: „Normalerweise lasse ich mir mindestens eine Woche Zeit, aber diesmal habe ich mich besonders angestrengt und es schon nach drei Tagen verschickt.“

Aus einem deutschen Adjektiv bekommt man ein Adverb primär nicht durch Ableitung, sondern indem man es einfach so, wie es ist, als Adverb benutzt. Es gibt unter Linguisten eine Minderheitsmeinung, die aus guten Gründen auch die englische Endung *-ly* nicht als Ableitung interpretiert, sondern als Deklination, und die Adjektiv und Adverb in einer einzelnen Wortart zusammenfasst. (Adjektiv : Adverb verhält sich dann analog zu Infinitiv : konjugiertes Verb, während es im Deutschen eher umgekehrt ist, d.h. Adverb : Adjektiv verhält sich so. Man könnte vielleicht auch im Englischen das Adjektiv als durch Weglassen von *-ly* dekliniertes Adverb auffassen, aber das fühlt sich irgendwie falsch an.)

Selbst im Englischen ist die Unterscheidung zwischen Adjektiven und Adverbien jüngeren Ursprungs und gilt nicht für alle Wörter dieser Wortarten. (Manchmal ist es auch schwer zu sagen, ob es sich in einem konkreten Satz um ein Adjektiv oder ein Adverb handelt.) Es gibt englische Adjektive wie *ugly, likely, deadly*, die auf *-ly* enden. Es gibt englische Adverbien wie *far, fast, straight*, die mit dem entsprechenden Adjektiv identisch sind, obwohl es nicht auf *-ly* endet. Es gibt englische Adjektive wie *slow, clean, deep*, bei denen man mit nur leichten stilistischen und Bedeutungsunterschieden die Wahl hat, das Adverb mit oder ohne *-ly* zu benutzen.

Die Endung *-ly* hatte auch im Englischen ursprünglich eine ganz andere Bedeutung. Sie wurde benutzt, um aus einem fast beliebigen Substantiv oder auch Adjektiv/Adverb ein neues Adjektiv/Adverb abzuleiten. Beispiele: *manly, namely, redly*. In diesem Sinne wird sie wohl allmählich durch *-ish* abgelöst. Diese veraltete Funktion von *-ly* im Englischen ist auch heute noch die im Wesentlichen einzige Funktion von *-lich* im Deutschen. Mit der Bildung von Adverbien aus Adjektiven hat das nichts zu tun. Ein deutsches Adjektiv wird zu einem Adverb, indem man es da verwendet, wo ein Adverb erwartet wird.

Man kann es auch so sehen, dass die moderne Funktion von *-ly* im Englischen ein Ersatz für die Deklination ist, an der man ganz früher auch im Englischen Adjektiv und Adverb unterscheiden konnte. Ähnlich wie der englische Inifinitiv, der sich heute kaum noch von den konjugierten Verbformen unterscheidet, heute sehr oft an einem *to* davor zu erkennen ist.

Comment: Huch, ja, das ist Quatsch. Ich schau mal, wie ich das korrigieren kann.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die sehr informative Erklärung!